# I'm trying to install stable difussion in Mac. Error installing gfpgan. Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'

Tags: python, stable-diffusion

When I'm trying to install stable diffusion in Mac, I've followed the tutorial until the part in installing gfpgan.

I'm a complete beginner in coding, so I'm not sure what's going on.

```
 Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'

stderr:   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [40 lines of output]
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.1.1
      Source dir: /private/var/folders/s1/cj_qqzrx6qz1n0b0fsym2ltr0000gn/T/pip-install-0ysv26de/scipy_1e9ddc71d73f4d519e1b9ce9743c55ac
      Build dir: /private/var/folders/s1/cj_qqzrx6qz1n0b0fsym2ltr0000gn/T/pip-install-0ysv26de/scipy_1e9ddc71d73f4d519e1b9ce9743c55ac/.mesonpy-7rbirvyn/build
      Build type: native build
      Project name: SciPy
      Project version: 1.10.1
      C compiler for the host machine: cc (clang 12.0.5 "Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)")
      C linker for the host machine: cc ld64 650.9
      C++ compiler for the host machine: c++ (clang 12.0.5 "Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)")
      C++ linker for the host machine: c++ ld64 650.9
      Cython compiler for the host machine: cython (cython 0.29.35)
      Host machine cpu family: aarch64
      Host machine cpu: aarch64
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-but-set-variable: NO
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-function: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-conversion: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-misleading-indentation: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types: YES
      Library m found: YES
      
      ../../meson.build:63:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['gfortran'], ['flang'], ['nvfortran'], ['pgfortran'], ['ifort'], ['ifx'], ['g95']]
      The following exception(s) were encountered:
      Running `gfortran --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gfortran'"
      Running `gfortran -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gfortran'"
      Running `flang --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'flang'"
      Running `flang -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'flang'"
      Running `nvfortran --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nvfortran'"
      Running `nvfortran -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nvfortran'"
      Running `pgfortran --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pgfortran'"
      Running `pgfortran -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pgfortran'"
      Running `ifort --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ifort'"
      Running `ifort -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ifort'"
      Running `ifx --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ifx'"
      Running `ifx -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ifx'"
      Running `g95 --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'g95'"
      Running `g95 -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'g95'"
      
      A full log can be found at /private/var/folders/s1/cj_qqzrx6qz1n0b0fsym2ltr0000gn/T/pip-install-0ysv26de/scipy_1e9ddc71d73f4d519e1b9ce9743c55ac/.mesonpy-7rbirvyn/build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
      + meson setup --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10 /private/var/folders/s1/cj_qqzrx6qz1n0b0fsym2ltr0000gn/T/pip-install-0ysv26de/scipy_1e9ddc71d73f4d519e1b9ce9743c55ac /private/var/folders/s1/cj_qqzrx6qz1n0b0fsym2ltr0000gn/T/pip-install-0ysv26de/scipy_1e9ddc71d73f4d519e1b9ce9743c55ac/.mesonpy-7rbirvyn/build --native-file=/private/var/folders/s1/cj_qqzrx6qz1n0b0fsym2ltr0000gn/T/pip-install-0ysv26de/scipy_1e9ddc71d73f4d519e1b9ce9743c55ac/.mesonpy-native-file.ini -Ddebug=false -Doptimization=2
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.0.1 -> 23.1.2
[notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
```

I tried installing Python in https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/ using the version Phyton 3.11.2

But then I have no idea what's going on.